# AS3 Dynamic Text with Vars

Tags: string, actionscript-3, textbox, flash-cs6

I am working on a project with a few dynamic text boxes. I want to have one of the boxes show the variable "frameWeightText" and them "lbs" Here is some of the code:

```
var frameWeightText:String;
var frameWeight:Number;

frameWeight = 16;
frameWeightText = frameWeight.toString();

base_info.frameWeightBox.text = frameWeightText + "lbs";
```

The text box only shows "lbs" but not 16 before that.

Answer (score 3):

Your code all looks fine to me, but have you made sure to [embed](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/embed-fonts-consistent-text-appearance.html) the font you're using? If you haven't, but the text field on the stage has "lbs" already typed in, that would explain only those characters showing up.

Comment: Totally agree. This is the only possible problem.

Answer (score 0):

David Mear is right. surfaspen you should embed fonts to library and actionscript